# Prevent fixed position nav bar from overlapping sticky footer

Tags: jquery, css

I would like a nav bar to stick to the bottom of the view port but prevent it from overlapping the fixed height sticky footer.

The markup is as follows:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<div id="command-bar"></div>
```

And the CSS is as per [cssstickyfooter.com](http://cssstickyfooter.com).

You can see an example at http://jsfiddle.net/z2C5S/2/.

#### Update

Getting closer with the following JavaScript, just seems to be a bit of overlap when scrolling back up very slowly (http://jsfiddle.net/z2C5S/16)

```
$(function () {

  var setCommandBarPosition = function () {
    var footerOffset = $("#footer").offset().top;
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    var weOverlappedFooter = ((windowHeight + scrollTop) >= (footerOffset + 40)); // + the height of the command bar

    $("p").html("Overlapped: " + weOverlappedFooter);

    if (weOverlappedFooter) {
      $("#command-bar").removeClass("affix-bottom");
    } else {
      $("#command-bar").addClass("affix-bottom");
    }
  };

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    setCommandBarPosition();
  });

  setCommandBarPosition();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/z2C5S/14/

Basically, add a secondary navigation bar that looks like the primary one and place it inside the footer. Give the footer a z-index above the main navigation, so when you scroll down, the footer and the secondary nav cover up the main navigation.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="second-command"></div>
</div>
<div id="command-bar"></div>

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
    overflow:auto;
    min-height: 800px
}
/* must be same height as the footer */
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -180px;
    /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 180px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #999;
    z-index:2;
}
/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    /* thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
    /* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}

#command-bar {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: #000;
   z-index:1;
}

#second-command {
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Yes, there is a small section where you will see one overlap the other but this is the easiest way I know in CSS.

Comment: I'm not after a CSS only solution and duplicating the command bar isn't really an option. Nice idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to achieve the desired effect.

I had to change my markup such that the command bar sat inside the main wrapper div. This was so that on smaller pages (with no scrolling required) the command bar would sit on top of the div without forcing a scroll bar.

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="command-bar">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

The following code is responsible for adjusting the command bar position based on the scroll position of the page. Essentially we are checking to see if the view port has overlapped the footer when scrolling:

```
$(function () {

  var setCommandBarPosition = function () {
    var footerOffset = $("#footer").offset().top,
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        commandBarHeight = $("#command-bar").height(),
        weOverlappedFooter = ((windowHeight + scrollTop - commandBarHeight) >= footerOffset);

    $("p").html("Overlapped: " + weOverlappedFooter);

    if (weOverlappedFooter) {
      $("#command-bar").removeClass("affix-bottom");
    } else {
      $("#command-bar").addClass("affix-bottom");
    }
  };

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    setCommandBarPosition();
  });

  setCommandBarPosition();
});
```

Aside from the standard sticky footer CSS, we make sure that the command bar is set to absolute when we have reached the footer:

```
#command-bar {
  bottom: 180px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
p {
  color: white;
}
#command-bar.affix-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/TKMaa.

Answer (score 0):

@BenFoster's answer didn't quite work for me, weOverlappedFooter was never true (maybe because I positioned the left bar with "top:" and not with "bottom" in the CSS).

For the webOverlapped calculation I used the following:

```
    footerOffset = $("footer").offset().top
    commandBarTop = 30; // had to copy this value from css, not completely DRY solution
    commandBarBottom = $("#command-bar").outerHeight( true)+navBarTop+$(window).scrollTop();
    weOverlappedFooter = ((commandBarBottom) >= footerOffset);
```

and for the CSS

```
affix-bottom {
    position:absolute;
    top:initial;
    bottom:40px;
}
```

Otherwise I used the rest of Ben's solution above.